# Java run ServerSocket on PC

Tags: java, android, sockets, tcp

A common problem for a common project: I'm trying to run a ServerSocket Java program on my local PC and connect to it from an Android client. As others have experienced, things go smoothly when the client connects to the local address (eg. 192.168.xxx.xxx). If I try to connect through the internet, nothing happens:

Now, here are the things I tried:

- Created inbound/outbound rules in Windows Firewall to allow traffic for the Server Port (3000)
- Used the public IP in the client socket (IP obtained here)
- Set up port forwarding on my router: inbound connection on port 3000 are redirected to the local IP of the server (eg. 192.1686.xxx.xxx again)
- Check that the IP address of the server is listening to the port 3000 using "netstat -anp tcp".
- Disabled any firewall on my router, just in case.

Still, there is no connection. Using this tool (https://www.canyouseeme.org/) I triedd checking that the port was visible (with the server app running of course), but nothing, all I get is a time out.

I'm out of options, I was hoping someone could show me what I'm missing.

Thanks.

Comment: What you've described should work in general. Unfortunately you don't give concrete details that could show how your setup is different from working ones, other than "it's not working", so I'm not sure how this question could be answerable by outsiders. Do you have any 3rd party firewalls, or antivirus programs that might include firewall functionality? Have you triple checked for typos (it can be really hard to catch one's own typos)? Maybe you could post the code that creates the ServerSocket, and images of the firewall & forwarding rules you set up?

Comment: Disable the firewall on your pc.

Comment: Your java server socket is not only bound to a local ip?

Comment: I also tried disabling the firewall, with no success. I have a VPN set up, which I turned off during testing. My java socket is manually bound to the local PC (192.168.whatever.whatever.)

Comment: Try to connect from locally running Android emulator, issue could be in raw TCP - some mobile ISPs don't allow such. So for example http/https on default ports will work from mobile client, but custom TCP connection  - not.

Comment: Well you should not bind your server socket to any ip.

Comment: Troubleshoot using a packet capture tool on the server, e.g. wireshark.

Answer (score -1):

(1) Does your PC where your server runs on have a public IP?
If you haven't applied for one and are running your code in a home or working environment, your computer only has a private IP. And considering the fact, your server and client connect well in the same LAN, the problem may be the IP.

(2)If you do have a public Ip, does your server listen on all IP address or just the LAN? Check the server bind IP is '0.0.0.0', and in ServerSocket constructor you can just set it to be null.

Comment: The question that was posted makes clear OP already understands this and does not have a public IP for their PC, and is trying to configure a workaround with port forwarding on the router, which they expect to have a public IP.

Comment: I'm using the public IP of the router, hoping to redirect incoming traffic to my local PC using port forwarding, which it appears is not working as I hope it would

Comment: @DanGetz "the router has a public IP and is used" is only stated in comments where a lot of routers don't really have a public IP

Comment: @user3494305 I made an experiment  with java SocketServer that follows most of your steps except that I tried with PC telnet not a mobile app and my case works. I think another direction is to test in your PC, telnet the public IP to see if it works. IF it works, then the problem may comes to the client part, or else the server and port redirection part.